# Only port 80 is slow

Tags: apache, tcp

I run apache 2.2 on my server and only 80 port is slow.

When I checked 80 port, it takes ten second.

```
user@myserver:~$ wget http://myserver/
--2013-10-04 07:41:56--  http://myserver/
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2013-10-04 07:42:06
```

But, I checked 443 port, it takes one second.

```
user@myserver:~$ wget https://myserver/
--2013-10-04 07:42:01--  http://myserver/
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2013-10-04 07:42:01
```

From my server itself, same result is appeared.

Perhaps, I think something limit the number of connection, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: You might have to ream the port out a bit. What with all the HTTP and other stuff that gets tunnelled through port 80, especially the advertisements, bits and even dropped packets tend to accumulate at the leading edge of the circumference and ultimately reduce the working diameter. Ports that don't get used so often don't have this problem to the same extent. Make sure to centre the reamer in the port and vertically, so you retain perfect circularity.